# Wordpress ‘Error establishing a database connection’ on first try only

Tags: mysql, wordpress

TLDR; start;

Wordpress website shows ‘Error establishing a database connection’ on first attempt only to search for items (after a long duration?).

TLDR; end;

I'm having this engineering nightmare of a problem where a bug occurs very rarely and unpredictably and cannot be reproduced which makes it very frustrating to solve.

My Wordpress website will show ‘Error establishing a database connection’ when users try to search for items using the search bar. If the page is refreshed it works.

After that the problem just never happens again. I tried clearing cache, reloading browser, trying different browsers, trying on my phone and never saw this problem again. But users are complaining that the search is not working and most users will not try to refresh the page and leave the website assuming there is a server error at this time.

I checked my database logs, settings and everything I can check to try to find a lead to no avail.

Anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Is it possible you're hitting the `max_connections` value on your SQL server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TheGentleman suggested, the problem was the max_connections setting in the mysql server. I discovered that I can turn on debugging:

put this anywhere in your wp-config.php file

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Which told me exactly what was the problem.

I was running WordPress on a public hosting service (1and1) and after some emails they just told me that they can't increase the value of max_connections. So I moved to a VPS server where I have full control over and:

https://electrictoolbox.com/update-max-connections-mysql/

problem solved.

PS. don't use 1and1 public hosting service for WordPress (or anything else).

Answer (score -1):

Try to check database connection details in the wp-config.php file, or you can contact with your hosting provider.

Comment: I did that. I didn't find any "error_on_first_connection = true" setting.